# Parallel debuggers

Tags: debugging, parallel-processing, distributed, mpi

I am trying to decide which parallel debugger to use.
So far I found not many open sources ones so my choices are:

- https://www.arm.com/products/development-tools/server-and-hpc/forge/ddt
- http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview-family/totalview.aspx

Which one do you recommend?
Are there anything else worthwhile?

Comment: A colleague wrote a few years ago a short technical report comparing the two - http://escholarship.org/uc/item/69h6031d .   Moral of the story: they're comparable, and the fact that there's competition in the market has improved the landscape considerably.  We use DDT now; I prefer the interface, and it now scales to much larger process counts than totalview does (but I suspect totalview will make up the difference shortly).  DDT also works on all our machines (x86, CUDA, Power); check to see if Totalview can cover all your platforms.

Comment: @Jon can you please post your comment as answer?  I want to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A colleague wrote a few years ago a short [technical report](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/69h6031d) comparing the two.  Moral of the story: they're comparable, and the fact that there's competition in the market has improved the landscape considerably. We use DDT now; I prefer the interface, and it now scales to much larger process counts than totalview does (but I suspect totalview will make up the difference shortly). DDT also works on all our machines (x86, CUDA, Power); check to see if Totalview can cover all your platforms.

Answer (score 1):

TotalView supports TCL scripting very nicely.  Had a nightmare system that consisted of 40+ interconnected processes.  TotalView's tcl interface allowed me to create a script that attached to them all at once at startup in an automated fashion.  Certain things would NOT have gotten fixed without that facility.